# SQL Server Error - Conversion overflowing int

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

I'm getting the following error on a simple INSERT INTO statement

```
The conversion of the nvarchar value '5551662080' overflowed an int column.
```

I understand that, the value exceeds the bounds of an INT, but I'm not converting to an INT anywhere.
The field in the source table is an NVARCHAR(MAX) in the destination I've tried FLOAT and BIGINT both fail with this same error.

Background is that the source table I have no control over - all fields are NVARCHAR(MAX) and the table contains data on over 6 million files that originated as the output of powershell scripts. I'm moving these into a table with more suitable data types.

Here's the SQL:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.File01 (
[Name]
,[Length]
,[Directory]
,[Extension]
,[CreationTime]
,[LastWriteTime]
,[IsFile]
)
SELECT 
    [Name]
    ,cast([Length] as Bigint)
    ,[Directory]
    ,[Extension]
    ,convert(datetime2,[CreationTime], 103)
    ,convert(datetime2,[LastWriteTime], 103)
    ,iif(isnull([Length],1)=1, 0, 1)
FROM dbo.FileData
```

The problem is in the file Length column - it all works fine otherwise. It works on the first 91k rows, just failing when it hits this big number.

All the references I can find point to triggers or stored procedures that have an INT conversion hidden somewhere, but that's not the case here - it's a brand new DB that only exists to do this job

*EDIT
Table structure for target table

```
Column Name Data type   Max Length  precision   scale   is_nullable 
Name        nvarchar    -1     0           0       0         0
Length      bigint       8    19           0       1         0
Directory   nvarchar    -1     0           0       1         0
Extension   nvarchar    -1     0           0       1         0
CreationTime    datetime2   8 27           7       1         0
LastWriteTime   datetime2   8 27           7       1         0
IsFile      bit         1      1           0       1         0
```

Comment: Hi @SurajKumar I'm afraid the column type is already Bigint. There's not an Int type anywhere to be seen

Comment: Can you please show table structure.

Comment: Table structure added @YogeshSharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try this just use the single quote as shown below.

```
iif(isnull([Length], '1') = '1', '0', '1')
```

OR

```
iif(isnull(Cast([Length] as Bigint), 1) = 1, 0, 1)
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b8337266c0189d78bb56365dc1cea1ea) demo.

Comment: That's not going to solve the problem - I need the value from the NVARCHAR in the first table (5551662080) to convert into the equivalent Bigint column in the second

Comment: OH,, I see, it's not my cast that's causing the problem - it is the boolean flag further down. I'll try that

Comment: @PerryW This is just `iif()` statement problem and their correction, nothing more than this with your existing logic. If `NVarchar` then use single quote or cast it as `BigInt'.

Comment: Yup, that's it - I was looking in the wrong  place for the problem - thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the `length` column in `file01` is an *integer*, not a *bigint*.   So, converting the column to a `bigint` doesn't help.

You can fix the problem using `try_convert()` or `try_cast()` -- to the appropriate type:

```
try_cast([Length] as int)
```

I recommend fixing the data type, though, because `file01` cannot represent the data you want to insert into it:

```
alter table file01 alter column length bigint;
```

If your table is really big, this might take a while, because all the data needs to be rewritten.